# $\varphi(f_n) - \varphi(g_n)\to 0$ in measure for $L^2-$bounded series $(f_n)$, $(g_n)$ with $f_n-g_n\to 0$ in $L^2$ and $|\varphi(x)|\le K(1+|x|^2)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ be a measure space with $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$, $(f_n)_{n\ge 1}$ and $(g_n)_{n\ge 1}$ be series of two real measurable functions such that: there exists a constant $M\ge 0$ satisfying $||f_n||_{L^2(\Omega)}, ||g_n||_{L^2(\Omega)} \le M$ for every $n\ge 1$, and that $f_n-g_n\overset{L^2}{\to} 0$ as $n\to\infty$. Suppose that a continuous function $\varphi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and a constant $K\ge 0$ satisfy $|\varphi(x)|\le K(1+|x|^2)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, must we have $\varphi(f_n) - \varphi(g_n)\overset{\mu}{\to} 0$ (converging in measure)?

The result is trivial if $\varphi$ is uniformly continuous, apart from which I have no idea currently. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $\delta>0$, and define $A_n := \{x\in\Omega,\ \vert\varphi(f_n(x))-\varphi(g_n(x))\vert>\delta\}$. We want to show that $\mu(A_n)\to0$. Let's choose some $\varepsilon>0$, and define for all $C>0$  :
$$
B_n := \{x\in\Omega,\ \vert f_n(x)\vert>C \text{ or } \vert g_n(x)\vert > C \}.
$$
Using the boundedness in $L^2$ :
$$
\mu(B_n)\cdot C^2
\leq \Vert f_n \Vert^2_{L^2(B_n)} + \Vert g_n \Vert^2_{L^2(B_n)}
\leq 2M^2
\ \Rightarrow \ 
\mu(B_n) \leq \frac{2M^2}{C^2},
$$
meaning we can take $C>0$ large enough so that $\mu(B_n) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ for all $n$.

Since $\Omega\setminus B_n = \{x\in\Omega,\ \vert f_n(x)\vert\leq C \text{ and } \vert g_n(x)\vert\leq C\}$, we can now use the uniform continuity of $\varphi$ over $[-C,C]$ to find $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that, for all $n\geq N$, $\mu(A_n\setminus B_n) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$, and so :
$$
\mu(A_n) = \mu(A_n \setminus B_n) + \mu(B_n) < \varepsilon.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your help!